# Google Apps Script: What is the correct way to check if I have access to a Google Spreadsheet by URL

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am currently writing a Google Apps Script inside a Google Sheet to read data from a list of spreadsheets (spreadsheet url is provided by the user). However, I cant seems to find a way to check if the url is valid or if user have access to the spreadsheet or not before calling `SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl()`.

I have written the following code to "validate" the url:

```js
for(int i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
  let spreadsheet = null
  try {
    spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(urls[i]);
  } catch (e) {
    continue;
  }

  // Continue to do other stuff to read data from spreadsheet...
}
```

This however has an issue, it was able to catch the first few 'You do not have permission to access the requested document.' exception. But after a certain number of exception had occur, I would get a permenant error that cant be caught, stopping the script all together.

Is there a better way to do this?

Minimal reproducible example:

1. Create 3 google sheet using different google account
2. Using a different google account, create a google sheet and add the following code into Code.gs

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Put any 3 real spreadsheet url that you do not have access to
  let urls = [
    "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gOyEAz0amm4RghpE4B7f26okU3PG3vWZkrfiC-SBlbw/edit#gid=0",
    "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Oia7ADu5BmYroUq1SLyDMHTJowrwSXOhCEyNO3nXmMA/edit#gid=0",
    "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HE_IXURpBr_FJN--mwLo6k9gih07ZEtDGBqYSk6KgiA/edit#gid=0",
  ]
  urls.forEach(url => {
    try {
      SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Unable to open this spreadsheet")
    }
  })
}

function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("Test").addItem("myFunction", "myFunction").addToUi()
}
```

3. Run the function once in the apps script panel and authorize the application
4. Refresh this google sheet
5. Wait for the Custom Menus to show up and press "Menu" > "myFunction"

As you can see, the `openByUrl()` call is sitting inside the try catch block, however when you run the function through custom menu, you will still get "Error: You do not have permission to access the requested document.".

Executions Log:
[image]

Comment: `But after a certain number of exception had occur, I would get a permenant error that cant be caught, stopping the script all together.` can you provide more details regarding that error? Because the `try/catch` is indeed the only way you can check whether you have access to the spreadsheet or not.

Comment: `I would get a permenant error that cant be caught` What error do you mean? Is it `You do not have permission to access the requested document`? Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @lamlichus i have added a minimal reproducible example

Comment: @soMarios I do realised later on that the script still runs normally, however at the end of execution, I will still get an error that cant be caught

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question, I thought that your situation might be due to the specification or a bug of `SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl`. If my understanding is correct, in order to avoid this issue, how about putting the method for checking whether the file can be used before `SpreadsheetApp`? In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From :

```
SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url)
```

#### To:

```
var fileId = url.split("/")[5];
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(file);
```

- In this modification, the file is retrieved with `DriveApp.getFileById(fileId)`. When `fileId` cannot be used, an error occurs. But in this case, try-catch can be correctly worked. By this, the issue of `SpreadsheetApp` doesn't occur.

Comment: This solved the issue, thanks!